# how to get status in c for system() commands

Tags: c, system

I want to get the status of command which i passed as a parameter to the system() function. suppose i pass "attrib +h E:/songs/lovingsong.mp3" as system("attrib +h E:/songs/lovingsong.mp3") since i know that the path give by me is not right , i.e there is no such folder songs in my E: drive so on console it says path not found.
How can i get "path not found" message in my c program or any status code ,so that i can know the command did not work.

```
/* system example : DIR */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* system, NULL, EXIT_FAILURE */

int main ()
{
  int i;
  printf ("Checking if processor is available...");
  if (system(NULL)) puts ("Ok");
    else exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  printf ("Executing command DIR...\n");
  i = system ("attrib +h E:/songs/lovingsong.mp3");
  //want to get status here
  printf ("The value returned was: %d.\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using [`SetFileAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx) directly (it’s what `attrib` probably does internally). It looks like it’s more complicated than a simple `system`, but it’s also probably easier than the complication of parsing the stderr and stdout of the `attrib` command.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the C11 standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) defines `system` in §7.22.4.8 (with its formal argument being called *string* below):

> If *string* is  a  null  pointer,  the `system` function  determines  whether  the  host environment has a command  processor. If *string* is  not  a  null  pointer,  the `system` function  passes  the  string  pointed to by  *string* to that command  processor to be executed in a manner which the implementation shall document; this might then cause the program calling
>   `system` to behave in a non-conforming manner or to terminate

So there is no clear definition, according to the C11 standard, of what `system` does. You need to dive into the documentation of your particular C11 implementation.

On POSIX (e.g. Linux or MacOSX), `system` is [required](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) to run the POSIX shell `/bin/sh` with the `-c` argument followed by the *string* and there is a complex chapter describing what is a POSIX shell.

Perhaps you want to pass a command which is [*redirecting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) the stderr of `attrib` to stdout, and read that stdout produced by your `attrib` command. On POSIX you could use [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) (with `pclose`) for that purpose. Maybe (and [probably](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx)) your implementation has something similar: `_popen`. And you also need to read the documentation of your `attrib` command.

**So your question is really [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific**. You need to dive into the documentation of your particular operating system.

And you might simply test (*before* running `system`) that the file `E:/songs/lovingsong.mp3` exists. Maybe use [`_access`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/access-waccess) (with perhaps a race condition if that file gets removed before running `attrib`).

Be also aware of the [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

<sup>PS. I don't know anything about [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), but you did not tag your question with Windows.</sup>

Comment: Just because the question wasn’t tagged Windows doesn’t mean you don’t know perfectly well that half of your answer is completely irrelevant to the OP.

Comment: My answer mentions `popen` (even with a link to Windows documentation) so is probably what  the OP wants.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose. I just feel like the note that Windows might be different should at least be more prominent.

Comment: Don't the mention "operating system specific" is enough?